# Select mutual followers excluding blocked contacts

Tags: mysql

Users Table

```
id   activated 
---  ------------ 
1       1
2       1
3       0
4       1
5       1
6       1
```

Follow table

```
follower_id   following_id 
------------ --------------
    1               2
    2               1
    4               2
    5               1
    3               2
    5               2
    6               1
    3               4
    6               2
    3               1
    4               1
```

Blocking table

```
blocking_id   blocked_id 
------------ --------------
    2               4
```

Let's say I am the user with the id of 2

Expected Result

```
   user_id      mutual_followers 
-------------  -----------------
      1               2
      5               0
      6               0
```

I want to get the mutual followers of users and exclude blocking or blocked and users whose activated is 0.

How can I get it done all the way by MySQL?

Comment: You should really also include the expected output to get the question across.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I provided more info including expected output

Comment: What is `others_id`?

Comment: There is only 1 non-activated user in your sample data: id = 3. Why is this user considered *mutual* (although must me rejected)?

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz Please provide a bigger sample size and the SQL statements to create and fill the tables. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: @forpas getting the mutual followers of users (1 and 2)

Comment: @forpas Why is this user considered mutual (although must me rejected)? it is not considered mutual, as you can see in the sample mutual followers are 0

Comment: Then why do you mention: *actually 2 but 1 blocked excluded and 1 non-active exluded*? Doesn't this imply that if user=3 was active the result should be 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz Please [edit] your question to include your definition of "mutual followers" for your application. I get conflicting definitions when checking the internet (like following each other or following the same other persons).

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz You have still not added the definition of "mutual followers". Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of "mutual followers", based on the provided sample data.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas 8.0.28.

Comment: me and my brother were following each other, he got pissed and blocked me, can I expect to find a mutual/partial relation between me and my brother in the Follow table after having been blocked by him? @UtkuDalmaz

Comment: @lemon normally mutual relation should be deleted on the following table but I kept it just for example purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use a CTE that returns all the followers of the user, filtered by your conditions to be active and non-blocked and then for each of the followers get their non-blocked followers.
Then filter the followers of the followers so that only the mutual followers are left (or none) and aggregate:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT f.follower_id user_id
  FROM Follow f
  INNER JOIN Users u ON u.id = f.follower_id AND u.activated
  LEFT JOIN Blocking b ON b.blocking_id = f.following_id AND b.blocked_id = f.follower_id 
  WHERE f.following_id = 2 AND b.blocked_id IS NULL  
)
SELECT c1.user_id, 
       COUNT(c2.user_id) mutual_followers 
FROM cte c1 
LEFT JOIN Follow f ON f.following_id = c1.user_id
LEFT JOIN Blocking b ON b.blocking_id = f.following_id AND b.blocked_id = f.follower_id
LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c2.user_id = f.follower_id
WHERE b.blocked_id IS NULL 
GROUP BY c1.user_id;
```

See the [demo1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=19ae073416c729cc01379269a6aa84de) or [demo2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dmfBhSAjGHJKffSLAp1kp4/0) (in case the 1st is inaccessible or sometimes does not run).

Comment: 1) fine 2) this still doesn't mean that your solution is efficient in an absolute way, don't discuss it relatively to others' solutions 3) fine. @forpas

Comment: @lemon you can judge the efficiency of a solution when you have a better one. Until now you don't have anything.

Comment: @lemon does this mean that when you posted your 1st comment you did not have a solution because you did not understand the requirement? Also, no you still don't have a solution because your *solution* is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243861/discussion-between-lemon-and-forpas).